# Can a document type (DOCTYPE) declaration referencing a Document Type Definition (DTD) be used in a SOAP body?

Tags: soap

I have read the SOAP rule stating: A SOAP message must NOT contain a DTD reference.  Does this refer to the SOAP Header or the entire message, including the SOAP Body which may be containing its own XML document (where the DTD reference is desired)?